# Extract Lists from tuple with a condition

Tags: python

I was trying to extract lists from a tuple with a condition that every X numbers in ascending order should be extracted in same list, using a list comprehension.

Example:

- Input: `(4,2,2,3,5,6,0,0,2)`
- Desired output: `[[4],[2,2,3,5,6],[0,0,2]]`

I tried the following:

```py
E=tuple([random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)])
Res=[E[x:y] for x in range(0,len(E)) for y in range(x+1,len(E)) if (y>x)]
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Extract N numbers inside a list [] that are in the ascending order from a tuple using a list comprehension.

Comment: Why do you have to use a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, simple logic to create new list already with the first element tuple. and then loop over tuple and if its current element is less then last element or not, if its smaller then `append element as a list` or `append element into the last list`.

Code:

```
import random
E=tuple([random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)]) 
E

ls=[[E[0]]]
[ls.append([E[e]])  if E[e]<E[e-1] else ls[len(ls)-1].append(E[e]) for e in range(1, len(E)) ]
ls
```

**OR**   Without pre-defining the first value

```
from itertools import pairwise
l=[[]]
[l[len(l)-1].append(y) if x-y < 0 else l.append([y]) for (x, y) in pairwise([e for e in (0,)+E])] ##Insert the dump 0 at first position
l
```

Input: `(7, 10, 7, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3, 5, 10)`
Output: `[[7, 10], [7], [2, 3, 7], [4], [3, 5, 10]]`

Input: `(0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 2, 3)`
Output: `[[0, 3, 4], [3], [0, 7], [0, 0, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to do this. You could use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) together with [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to get the random numbers which is used as index to split.

```
import random
import numpy as np

lst = [4,2,2,3,5,6,0,0,2]
number_of_splits = 4
random.seed(42)
random_splits = sorted(random.sample(set(range(1,len(lst)-1)),number_of_splits-1))
print(random_splits)

result = [list(elem) for elem in np.split(lst, random_splits)]
print(result)
```

```
[1, 6, 7]
[[4], [2, 2, 3, 5, 6], [0], [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do this without a list comprehension - i.e., a straightforward loop like this:

```
from random import randint as RANDINT

t = 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 2
out = []
offset = 0
while offset < len(t):
    e = RANDINT(1, len(t)+1-offset)
    out.append(list(t[offset:offset+e]))
    offset += e
print(out)
```

**Output (example):**

```
[[4], [2, 2], [3], [5, 6, 0, 0], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use slice to mark start and end of sub-lists

```
t=(4,2,2,3,5,6,0,0,2)

split_list=[0]+[x for x in range(len(t)) if t[x]<t[x-1]]
split_list_end=[x for x in range(len(t)) if t[x]<t[x-1]]
split_list_end.append(len(t))

[list(t[x]) for x in [slice(x[0],x[1]) for x in list(zip(split_list,split_list_end))]]
```